# A space before function call in c++

Tags: c++, syntax, whitespace

Is the following code allowed in c++?
`a. foo()`
(note the space before "foo")

I would assume not, but the compiler doesn't complain.

Comment: Why do you assume `not`?

Comment: are you assuming the compiler is wrong?

Comment: No, I don't assume the compiler is wrong :)
I just never saw code written like this, so it looked weird.

Comment: It is allowed, but it sure looks strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is valid C++ code:

From  [C++ Standard - ANSI ISO IEC 14882 2003.pdf](https://openassist.googlecode.com/files/C++%20Standard%20-%20ANSI%20ISO%20IEC%2014882%202003.pdf), chapter 2.6:

> There are five kinds of *tokens*: identifiers, keywords, literals, operators, and other separators. **Blanks**, horizontal and vertical tabs, newlines, formfeeds, and comments (collectively, “white space”), as described below, **are ignored** except as they serve to separate tokens.

The same chapter defines that a *punctuator* is also a *token*.

Chapter *2.12 Operators and punctuators* defines that `.` is a *punctuator*.

Answer (score 3):

Should be fine, as far as I know the compiler strips out all whitespace (tab, newline, space) unless they are in a String (i.e. "in a string").

[edit] you should also not put whitespace in operators (i.e. `i++` is different from `i+ +` and `foo()` is different from `fo o()`).

[edit] As mentioned in another answer, whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines, comments) is also used to separate operators such as `void bar()` vs. `voidbar()`

Comment: Nope. `x + = 42;` wouldn't be compiled. It strips whitespaces only between **tokens**

Comment: They are stripped by lexer, because he generates tokens

Comment: The compiler doesn't strip _any_ white space.  The front end breaks the input up into tokens, ignoring white space _between_ tokens (but no where else).  You can introduce white space before and after the `.` in the example because the `.` is a token.  You cannot introduce extra white space in `foo` or `++`, because `foo` and `++` are tokens.  You must insert white space in `voidbar` because otherwise, the maximum munch rule would make it a single token.  (All of this on the results of the preprocessor, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

Allowed.

`.` is just operator, like `+`, `::`, `->`, `&&` and others.

Spaces are ignored in your case

Generally speaking spaces removed after lexer generates tokens from source file.

Comment: That's weird. How about "<::" vs "< ::" ? It does make a difference in my experience ... "<:" may be interpreted as "[". Spaces are not always ignored, or is there something I didn't catch ?

Comment: Don't forget the maximum munch rule.  When breaking the source up into tokens, the scanner will read as far forward as possible, independently of any surrounding context.  So given `"<::"`, it first tries for the longest token, which is `"<:"` (a synonym for `"'"`). Which means that `"<::"`, is `"["`, `":"`, and not `"<"`, `"::"`. Despite the fact that `"<"`, `"::"` might result in a legal progream, but `"["`, `":"` never can.

Comment: @JamesKanze really so, but I only stated that after lexer pass there is no more spaces =)

Answer (score 2):

You can have as many or as few spaces anywhere before or after any token in C or C++. The only rule is that tokens need to be separated by either a different token (that is, something not a letter (A-Z, a-z, _) or a digit [and where relevant, a token may also contain ., +  or -, such as floating point numbers).

So

```
 a.foo()
 a. foo();
 a . foo (    ) ;
 a
   . 
foo 
  (
 )
;
```

are all the same.

But you have to have a space between certain tokens, particularly those consisting of only "letters & digits" (see above):

```
voidfoo()
```

is not the same as

```
void foo();
```